# Adjust Screen Brightness by scrolling up and down on the screen and without using a seekbar

Tags: android, brightness, swipe-gesture, onscrolllistener

is it possible to adjust screen brightness by simply swiping up and down on the screen, which method should i use to get it ?

with the help of a seekbar i did it, but it's good to know how could it be done using swipe gesture as it'll be helpful for many others.

It is easy to adjust screen brightness using a seekbar by applying the following method on the seekbar change listner.

```
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            System.putInt(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
            LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
            layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255;
            window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            //Nothing handled here
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            if(progress<=20)
            {
                brightness=20;
            }
            else
            {
                brightness = progress;
            }
            float perc = (brightness /(float)255)*100;
            txtPerc.setText((int)perc +" %");
        }
    });   
}
```

Do anybody know how to do it without a seekbar ?

Comment: Can't you take any touch events of view and use that to do so??

Comment: with ontouchEvent i can set minimum and maximum brightness, but i won't be able to get the intermediate values (brightness), i think, onscroll is the key for this answer but i am unaware of how to do this as i am a rookie in android.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but for anyone looking for it now, you may use this android library  [Swipper](https://github.com/sdsmdg/Swipper).